# Has_many, Through: Saving Joiner Table Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have three classes:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

I am trying to create a new Patient record through an existing Physician record.

```
doctor = Physician.first  
sick_person = doctor.patients.new 
sick_person.save
```

What is happening is that the patient record gets saved but the joiner record, appointments, doesn't get created. I have been reading a few forums and they suggested I use an inverse_of (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6161#issuecomment-6330795, which seems not right when using a :through.

Any body have any ideas of how to get the joiner table recorded? I know I could also create the patient record first and then create the appointments record afterwards with that patient id, but I'm wondering if there is more of an eloquent solution.

Comment: Same results :/ The patient record gets saved but not the appointment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
doctor = Physician.first
sick_person = Patient.new
doctor.patients << sick_person
```

Comment: I wish I could you a cookie. Thanks :)